# Facebook Like Button Reloads For Each Page

Tags: html, css, facebook-like, google-custom-search, twitter-follow

I know this sounds petty, but whenever I switch from page to page, the facebook "like" button takes a little while to load. It looks ugly because once it DOES load, it pushes over the "follow" button on Twitter. The google custom search bar does the same thing usually, but faster.

**I just want the search bar / facebook button / follow button to load quickly and NOT push each other around.**

Here is the current website: http://www.blueskullgames.com

(if you click from page to page on the navbar you will see what I mean)

Any suggestions?

Side Note: I am using a single php custom header for all of my pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each time you either refresh the page or go to a new page, it will make a request to both Twitter and Facebook to get the Javascript files, they've tried to lower the loading time by loading the scripts asynchronously. What you could do is hide the div that holds the buttons on page load, and then fade it in after x amount of time. The more HTTP requests you have on the page to external sites the longer the page load time is going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facebook button is in an iframe. Add a width to your CSS for the class fb-like. Make sure you do it so it can expand to 4 digits in the counter "balloon"  For Rivals.com I did 132px width on the iframe so it does not show up and bully other tags around by displacing them.